# Is this the right way to set a value to a variable in a mysql trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers

So I have this variable configId and I set it's value to 1 but the result is different from

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS input_verification;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER input_verification 
AFTER INSERT ON InputHistory FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE configId integer;
    SET @configId := 1;
        IF( SELECT count(*)FROM InputHistory JOIN Input on InputHistory.inputId = Input.inputId WHERE InputHistory.inputHistoryOrderNumber=Input.inputOrderNumber AND InputHistory.inputHistoryStatus >= 300)=0 THEN
    UPDATE Configuration SET configurationReady = true WHERE configurationId= configId;
    END IF;
END $$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

this:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS input_verification;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER input_verification 
AFTER INSERT ON InputHistory FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE configId integer;
    SET @configId := 1;
        IF( SELECT count(*)FROM InputHistory JOIN Input on InputHistory.inputId = Input.inputId WHERE InputHistory.inputHistoryOrderNumber=Input.inputOrderNumber AND InputHistory.inputHistoryStatus >= 300)=0 THEN
    UPDATE Configuration SET configurationReady = true WHERE configurationId= 1;
    END IF;
END $$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

Where I put directly the value 1 to the update statement.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put the `@` sigil on local variables you declared in the body of your trigger.

In MySQL, variables with the `@` sigil are [user-defined variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html). You don't need to declare these. But they have scope outside your trigger. If they have a value before your trigger executes, the trigger can read that value. If you change the value of such a variable inside the trigger, the value will be preserved after the trigger is done.

Whereas variables without the `@` sigil are local variables. You must use DECLARE to create these variables, as you have done above. They are limited to the scope of the body they are declared in, i.e. in this case, the variable is only visible within this trigger.

Don't mix them. Just think of `configId` and `@configId` as different variables. In fact, they are different variables. Setting one does not change the value of the other.

Comment: but still without the @ i have the same problem, the result is different